# Test if icon was applied by WM_SETICON and remove it

Tags: winapi

I am trying to use `SendMessage` to test if the currently dislayed on window  was applied by `WM_SETICON`, and if it is then I would like to remove it so the `SetClassLongPtr` icon comes through. Is this possible?

Doing `WM_GETICON` is not returning `null` when icon was not applied with `WM_SETICON` (ie: if its using unchanged icon, or if icon was changed with `SetClassLongPtr`) it is instead returning whatever is showing.

Comment: What makes you believe that this is possible. This seems like a classic XY question.

Comment: Use `GetClassLongPtr` if you want to get the class icon handle (if it has one).

Comment: Do not test, there is no point.  Simply send WM_SETICON to set the class icon.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks all for the replies. reason i need to test thouh is because I dont want to override icons already set by WM_SETICON by some one else. :(

Comment: Hard to make sense of that.  Do nothing.

Comment: @HansPassant haha what I mean is, the application is firefox, it sets icon with SetClassLong. Add-ons are alowed to chaned icons, and when they do Firefox uses WM_SETICON. So I want to WM_SETICON to all windows to which an addon didnt chane. I did some adjustin to my WM_GETICON code and it is returnin 0 on windows which do not have a custom icon, is this reliable behavior o WM_GETICON? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can see you being able to this reliably is to use a message hook via `SetWindowsHookEx()` to intercept all of the `WM_SETICON` messages being sent to FireFox windows so you know which ones you can skip when needed.

Comment: So is WM_GETICON returning 0 not expected if there is no WM_SETICON set?

Comment: `DefWindowProc(WM_GETICON)` returns 0 if `WM_SETICON` has not been sent, unless you are requesting `ICON_SMALL2` to get a system icon. So if you are not getting 0 then either `WM_SETICON` has been sent and you do not know it, or the app is likely handling `WM_GETICON` to return another icon instead of calling `DefWindowProc()`.